# Separating multiple objects from one programmatically

Tags: javascript, loops, javascript-objects

I have an object with multiple tasks. The challenge is to sort them into separate objects which I have managed to do with the code that follows. I would like to know how this can be adjusted to a state where the loop will sort the tasks without having to program it separately (Like a i++ sort of function). Any ideas how to accomplish this?

```
const tasks = {
    title1: "Quiet Time",
    title2: "Study",
    title3: "Go Jogging",
    title4: "Eat Breakfast",
    description1: "",
    description2: "",
    decription3: "This is going to help to reach my goals and my life to the fullest",
    decription4: "",
    date1: "05/02/2020",
    date2: "01/02/2020",
    date3: "tomorrow",
    date4: "today",
    time1: "08:12",
    time2: "13:15",
    time3: "12:36",
    time4: "13:25",
    completed1: false,
    completed2: true,
    completed3: false,
    completed4: true,
    priority1: "red",
    priority2: "yellow",
    priority3: "black",
    priority4: "white",
    tags1: ["Personal", "Work", "School"],
    tags2: ["Personal", "School", "Diary Entry"],
    tags3: ["Content Creation", "Personal"],
    tags4: ["Personal"]
}

const task1 = {};
const task2 = {};
const task3 = {};
const task4 = {};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(tasks)) {
    if (key.endsWith('1')) {
        task1[key] = value;
    }
    if (key.endsWith('2')) {
        task2[key] = value;
    }
    if (key.endsWith('3')) {
        task3[key] = value;
    }
    if (key.endsWith('4')) {
        task4[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By matching the trailing digit, you can take that to put it into the appropriate object.

I'm assuming `decription3` `decription4` is a typo.

```js
const tasks = {
    title1: "Quiet Time",
    title2: "Study",
    title3: "Go Jogging",
    title4: "Eat Breakfast",
    description1: "",
    description2: "",
    description3: "This is going to help to reach my goals and my life to the fullest",
    description4: "",
    date1: "05/02/2020",
    date2: "01/02/2020",
    date3: "tomorrow",
    date4: "today",
    time1: "08:12",
    time2: "13:15",
    time3: "12:36",
    time4: "13:25",
    completed1: false,
    completed2: true,
    completed3: false,
    completed4: true,
    priority1: "red",
    priority2: "yellow",
    priority3: "black",
    priority4: "white",
    tags1: ["Personal", "Work", "School"],
    tags2: ["Personal", "School", "Diary Entry"],
    tags3: ["Content Creation", "Personal"],
    tags4: ["Personal"]
};

const tasksSorted = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(tasks)) {
    const num = key.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    tasksSorted[num] ?? = {};
    tasksSorted[num][key] = value;
}

console.log(tasksSorted);
```

Comment: Amazing answer, solved it! Thank you so much! I will need to read up about this part to understand what it does.

  const num = key.match(/\d+$/)[0];
  tasksSorted[num] ??= {};

Comment: Would be nice of you if you vote up and accept the answer if it was useful @EthanNaidu

Comment: Definitely! Haha I need to wait 10 minutes before I can click on solve and do not have enough reputation to upvote it. @rustyBucketBay